# Ruby documentation over Symbol objects is misleading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I'm a newbie to Ruby and like others I had trouble wrapping my head around Ruby symbols. I know this subject has been brought up many times but I believe this post might slightly differ from the others. If not, my apologies. Take for instance this piece of code from the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).

```
module One
  class Fred
  end
  $f1 = :Fred
end
module Two
  Fred = 1
  $f2 = :Fred
end
def Fred()
end
$f3 = :Fred
$f1.object_id   #=> 2514190
$f2.object_id   #=> 2514190
$f3.object_id   #=> 2514190
```

My gripe is that it makes us think there is a link between the class, the module or the function and the `:Fred` symbol. No wonder people ask things like "can I assign a value to a symbol" or is the symbol a reference to another thing.

This code adds to the confusion :

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

    layout :which_layout

    def index
        ...
    end

    private

    def which_layout
        if condition
            "layout1"
        else
            "layout2"
        end
    end
end
```

At first, I thought there was a reference to the function but in fact it's just that the behavior of the [layout](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout) method will vary base on whether we'll pass a `String` (the template name) or a `Symbol` (call the method specified by the symbol) as stated by the documentation. (Does it look for a `method.to_sym` that is equivalent to the symbol we passed as argument?)

What I believe I've read however is that when creating a class, his symbol counterpart will be automatically created, that is :Fred will already exist in subsequent calls. But that's just it?

My question is : why did they have to include a class, a variable and a function to illustrate this? The context? Then why having the same name? Why not just do :

```
$f1 = :Fred
$f2 = :Fred
$f3 = :Fred

$f1.object_id   #=> 2514190
$f2.object_id   #=> 2514190
$f3.object_id   #=> 2514190
```

Comment: I agree, it's very confusing.

Comment: Maybe they're trying to differentiate between the various types of things called `Fred`, or not. Keep in mind that matz isn't a native English speaker and a lot of this probably originated with him. Might be worth doing `def m;end` in `irb`, the result of that expression is `:m` and `(def m;end).object_id == :m.object_id`; or that might just confuse things further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a symbol Ruby looks at list of existing symbols so when you reuse a symbol you are not creating a separate object in memory.

```
irb(main):006:0> :foo.object_id == :foo.object_id
=> true
```

You can contrast this with a string:

```
irb(main):007:0> "foo".object_id == "foo".object_id
=> false
```

This combined with the fact that they are so cheap to compare is what makes symbols so effective as hash keys.

What that pretty confusing example demonstrates is that symbols are not private to a scope - the table of symbols is global. It would be a bit less confusing if an instance variable was used instead of a global variable. I think it also attempts to demonstrate that module and class names are constants.

```
irb(main):016:0> Fred = Module.new do; end # this is the same as using the module keyword
irb(main):017:0> Fred.object_id != :Fred.object_id
=> true
```

Which means that `Fred` is a reference to the module while `:Fred` is a value (a symbol).

Symbols like strings are a value and thus cannot be a used as a reference. This is very much like `true`, `false` and `nil` which are singleton objects.

```
irb(main):008:0> true.class
=> TrueClass
irb(main):09:0> true.object_id == true.object_id
=> true
# you can even use the singletons as hash keys
irb(main):010:0> { true => 1, false => 2, nil => 3 }[true]
=> 1
```

The Rails example is not really that complicated. `:which_layout` is just an argument passed to the layout method. The layout method has a conditional which uses Object#send to dynamically call the :which_layout method if it exists. A string argument is instead used straight away to construct a glob.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is it's meant to illustrate the fact that all of the other "Fred's" do nothing to alter the fact that the symbol `:Fred` is unchanged in every context.  Maybe changing the `object_id` list at the bottom of the example to something like this would make it more clear:

```rb
p One::Fred.object_id  #=> 70222371662500
p Two::Fred.object_id  #=> 3
p Fred().object_id     #=> 8
p $f1.object_id        #=> 2514190
p $f2.object_id        #=> 2514190
p $f3.object_id        #=> 2514190
```

Comment: I am not sure this makes anything clearer as your first 3 `Fred`s are not symbols at all  but rather a `Class`,an `Integer`, and `nil` (in that order)